# Invalid Cast Exception Occurred

Tags: vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2012

I am getting the following error:

Invalid Cast Exception Occurred
  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[WindowsApplication1.DesignSpec]'
  to type 'WindowsApplication1.DesignSpec'

on the following test code:

```
Dim prodSku As String = "11037"
Dim designSpec As DesignSpec = From row In dbLocal.DesignSpecs Where row.Name = prodSku Select row
```

I have searched high and low and have tried numerous options, but obviously not the right option. Any help in helping me use the right syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards and thank you in advance for your help!

PS: I know that this sounds kind of cheesy, but this is my first post (hopefully I've posted it adequately). I have followed many threads which have been incredibly helpful but I am unable to give any an up vote because I don't have the reputation points -- truly! If this is a good enough question maybe everyone will vote it up to give me enough reputation points so I can return the favor of everyone else's assistance. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linq query will return a collection (of `DesignSpec`'s), whereas you are trying to assign it to a single instance.

You'll need to apply a filter to the collection that extracts a single instance - e.g. `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()`, `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, etc depending on what makes most sense based on the expected output of the query.

Keep in mind that using the `Single` variants will result in an exception if the query happens to return more than one instance, whereas the `First` variants will cope with this ok as they simply return the first instance found.

Comment: THANK YOU!! for your prompt reply! This worked perfectly:

Dim prodSku As String = "11037"
Dim designSpec As DesignSpec = (From row In dbLocal.DesignSpecs Where row.Name = prodSku Select row).SingleOrDefault

I can't vote your answer up but thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have not actually executed the query yet. What you have done is described how to execute the query.

To actually execute the query use:

- `FirstOrDefault()` to return the first matching element or null
- `SingleOrDefault()` to return matching element or null (this will check that there is only one matching element). If there are more than one matching elements an exception will be thrown
- `First()` to return the first matching element or throw an exception if none is found
- `Single()` to return matching element or throw an exception when none are found or more than one is found.